Elementary change of variable in an ODE that makes me doubt
I am quite ashamed of the level of my question, but I have this ODE -- it is a simplified version -- and my concern is only with the left hand side:
$$ \dot v=kv$$
which I need to rewrite in terms of c, and we have $c=\exp(-v^*/v) $, where $v^*$ is a constant. Hence $ v=-v^*/\ln c$, and personally, I would write:
$$ \dot v = \frac{dv}{dc}\frac{dc}{dt}=\frac{v^*}{c\ln^2c}\dot c$$
which leads to:
$$\dot c=\frac{-kv^*}{\ln c} \frac{c\ln^2c}{v^*}=-kc\ln c$$
However, a colleague of mine writes:
$$ \dot v=\frac{v^*\dot c}{\ln^2c}$$
which leads to:
$$ \dot c=\frac{\ln^2c}{v^*}\frac{-kv^*}{\ln c}=-k\ln c$$
Who's right? I am under the impression my version is the right one but my colleague says otherwise...
Thanks for any help !

Yours looks correct

OK, thanks a lot !
